# tikz euclide \tkzMarkAngle causing error in bounding box?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am experiencing strange behaviour with tkz-euclide.

The `\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](P,R,S)` command in the code below seems to mess up the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){S}
\tkzDefPoint(42:20){P}
\tkzDefPoint(0:21.1){R}
\tkzDrawSegments[thick](S,P P,R R,S)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](S)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](P)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](R)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](P,R,S)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 3.5](P,R,S){$65^{\circ}$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](R,S,P)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 3.5](R,S,P){$42^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left](S,P){$20$ m}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This above code produces the correct picture but not centered, whereas the following code (with a single line commented out) produces a picture that does get centered.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){S}
\tkzDefPoint(42:20){P}
\tkzDefPoint(0:21.1){R}
\tkzDrawSegments[thick](S,P P,R R,S)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](S)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](P)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](R)
%\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](P,R,S)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 3.5](P,R,S){$65^{\circ}$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](R,S,P)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 3.5](R,S,P){$42^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left](S,P){$20$ m}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can get my picture centered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — In fact, I get an `Undefined control sequence` at `\tkzMarkAngle` and `\tkzLabelAngle`. Which package do provide these commands?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, it comes from a library to tikz, to be used for Euclidean geometry.

Comment: I've edited my code above.

Comment: The `label` (which is empty in this case) is placed at the wrong position. This updates the bounding box and thus creates a wider TikZ picture with a flush-left triangle and a lot of white space.

Answer (score 5):

The empty but still used `label` is set at the wrong position.

```
\node[shift=<somewhere>] at (<somewhere else>) …
```

doesn't work but

```
\node at ([shift=<somewhere>] <somewhere else>) …
```

or

```
\path[shift=<somewhere>] node at (<somewhere else>) …
```

does.

With the help of [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and its `\patchcmd` macro one can fix this without any hassle.

I took the liberty to include the `\tkzLabelAngle` right into the `\tkzMarkAngle` command.

I also included the `\tkzMarkAngle` between `S,P,R` which would have had a misplaced label also.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\tkz@MarkAngle{\node[lbstyle,shift={(\tkz@ax,\tkz@ay)}] at (\labelangle:\tkz@dist ){\tkz@mklabel};}
                       {\node[lbstyle] at ([shift={(\tkz@ax,\tkz@ay)}]\labelangle:\tkz@dist ){\tkz@mklabel};}% or \path[shift=…] node[lbstyle] at …;
                       {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){S}
\tkzDefPoint(42:20){P}
\tkzDefPoint(0:21.1){R}
\tkzDrawSegments[thick](S,P P,R R,S)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](S)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](P)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](R)
\tkzMarkAngle[label=$65^{\circ}$, dist=3.5, size=2](P,R,S)
\tkzMarkAngle[label=$42^{\circ}$, dist=3.5, size=2](R,S,P)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](S,P,R)
\tkzLabelSegment[above left](S,P){$20$ m}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The macro has been changed int the next version